# Nativescript angular app breaking with "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Too many receivers, total of 1000, registered for pid"

Tags: java, android, nativescript, zxing, nativescript-angular

I've creating a nativescript application which uses the `nativescript-barcodescanner` plugin to scan and decode qr codes. This application is intended to be used to scan a lot of qr codes, but not in consecutive order. However, after a 1000 scans, the application is breaking with the following exception.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {org.nativescript.test/com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Too many receivers, total of 1000, registered for pid: 15623, callerPackage: org.nativescript.test
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4021)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4053)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:51)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1955)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7078)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Too many receivers, total of 1000, registered for pid: 15623, callerPackage: org.nativescript.test
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1974)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:19
                    // Allocate time for this cycle to end before issueing a validate request. Attempting to fix Fragment issue on some
                    // mobile devices34)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1884)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.registerReceiver(IActivityManager.java:3684)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1567)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1528)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1516)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:636)
    at com.google.zxing.client.android.InactivityTimer.onResume(InactivityTimer.java:69)
    at com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.onResume(CaptureActivity.java:222)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1416)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7609)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4013)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.registerReceiver(ActivityManagerService.java:25447)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact$registerReceiver$(IActivityManager.java:10896)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:126)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:4162)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:739)
```

After attempting to debug the issue, from what i've found, it seems that when calling the `BarcodeScanner.scan` function offered by the `nativescript-barcodescanner` plugin, an Activity is started for result as per [this code](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-barcodescanner/blob/edafe47274331e1c629634af66518e74a71461d7/src/barcodescanner.android.ts#L223), which in turn, a receiver is registered by the [google zxing library](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/24a5f9c65457e21ec5bf4331dd7eb07e49eb51d8/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/InactivityTimer.java#L71) (used by this plugin). What seems to be the issue is that upon a successful scan, when the Activity returns the result, the google zxing library is not doing the necessary clean ups, resulting with dangling receivers registered. Note that when the scanner is closed by pressing the back button, the clean ups are carried out as expected.

Any help about going around this issue would be appreciated.

## Edit: Added link to github repo for reproduction

https://github.com/jeanpaulattard/nativescript-barcodescanner-demo

Comment: Can you share a sample project where issue can be reproduced? By the way, are you literally scanning 1000 objects before hitting this issue?

Comment: Yes I made it such that it automatically reopens the scanner after a successful scan, and let the phone scanning for around an hour and a half. I'll try to get it on playground, and add it to issue.

Comment: Added sample code, because the plugin is not supported in playground

Comment: Sorry, I meant a Github link or something. I understand it's not supported in Playground.